How to change Swagger URL in Spring Boot application from https://**abc**.com/swagger-ui.html to https://**xyz**.com/swagger-ui.html
I am new to Spring Boot and would like to know how to change the Swagger URL to a new one.
For example,
current swagger link : abc.com/swagger-ui.html
new swagger link :  xyz.com/swagger-ui.html


Does this answer your question? how to do friendly base url for swagger 2.8.0
